# What is the correct way to iterate over multivalue items of a form element in D7?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm sure there is a function to help with this by I can't find it in the API docs. What I want to do is: in a hook_form_alter, iterate over all of an element's items and and manipulate them.

The example form below is from a bean form which has a multivalue field collection called field_listing_articles. I want to iterate over all the instances of that element. They are located in the form under field_listing_articles -> und -> 0, 1, 2 etc

If I do a foreach and iterate over $form['field_listing_articles'][LANGUAGE_NONE] I will pick up all the other (non-numeric) parts of the form at that level. I realise I could put an if is_numeric condition in there but I'm sure there is a more 'Drupal' way of doing this.

Any advice appreciated.

```
$form    
--label  
--title  
--view_mode  
--bean  
--actions  
--#validate  
--#submit  
--#parents  
--#entity  
--field_listing_articles  
----#type  
----#attributes  
----#weight  
----#tree  
----#language  
----und  
------0  
------1  
------2  
------3  
------4  
------5  
------6  
------#theme  
------#field_name  
------#cardinality  
...etc
```

Comment: So far I've found the function [element_children](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/element_children/7) which looks like it will do the trick.   Example code:  
$children = element_children($form['field_listing_articles'][LANGUAGE_NONE]);  
foreach ($children as $delta) {  
  // Do manipulation here.  
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[element_children()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/element_children/7) returns any array's key that doesn't start with *#*, used for properties in form API arrays, and in rendering arrays. It doesn't return numeric keys, as the function would pass to your code an array key such as `"item"`, for example.

Instead of using the constant `LANGUAGE_NONE`, I would use [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7), which returns the values for the language currently set for the field, which could not be for the `LANGUAGE_NONE` language.

Comment: "It doesn't return numeric keys" - could you clarify? If I have a form element under `$form['something'][$numeric_id]` it will be omitted? Function's code does not look like it would.